# Missing frames using X264 to record video using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have some code to record video using openCV. The code works fine when I use the `MJPG` codec, but it produces very large videos.

I would like to produce smaller videos so I've passed the value `X264` to `CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')`. This seems to work, I don't get any warnings, but I notice that there are frames missing.

I recorded a 20 second video at 10 frames per second, then I played it with mplayer and the video only lasted 2 seconds.

Here is the guts of the code that I'm using:

```
    VideoCapture cap(dev); // open the default camera
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, fps);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1024);
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat testFrame;
    cap >> testFrame;
    cap >> testFrame;
    cap >> testFrame;


    Size outSize = Size(testFrame.cols, testFrame.rows);
    //VideoWriter writer(filename, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), fps, outSize, true); //Works
    VideoWriter writer(filename, CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'), fps, outSize, true); //Missing frames
    int count = 0;
    for(; ;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

        writer.write(frame);

    }
```

I should also add that this is running on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 64 bit on an Odroid C2 board.

Comment: h264 encoding is expensive, probably you are missing frames because it only manages to capture+encode with 1 fps on your hardware. Can you try to encode a video instead of a live camera stream? So that no INPUT frame is missing. Maybe you can tune the encoder settings to allow faster encoding (maybe with less compression), but I don't know how this can be done in openCV.

Comment: Yeah that seems plausible, processing power is a limitation on the board that we're using. Could you recommend a different type of encoding that is maybe a little more lightweight? Also I have ordered a logitech C920 which apparently has onboard h264 compression, do you think that will help?

Comment: onboard h264 compression won't help you in opencv, because during capturing you decode the encoded camera frames and later you'd encode them again the same way you're doing it now. If you are able to directly stream the video to file (without encoding) this would probably help, but I can't help you there. Remember that openCV is for working with images (computer vision) so it might not be the optimal choice for just recording a video, since openCV always captures and transforms the images to be plain BGR which will consume some processing time. Does your board have a gpu?

Comment: in general, encoding is often expensive, you could try to reduce the image size (capturing size) or resize the image to be smaller. This should reduce the encoding time :)